# Roo - add custom finder

Tags: spring-roo

I used Roo to create a project that uses existing database. 
Im able to create dynamic finders, but I want to implement custom finder that will receive 4 parameters and use some of them to create Like condition and others for equals condition.

What is the best way to do this with Roo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended pattern is to edit the .java source file for your entity and define the new finder there. You might like to create a dynamic finder and then copy the style from the corresponding entityname_Roo_Finder.aj file. Please note manually-created finders do not appear in the automatically-created web scaffold (whereas dynamic finders will).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to copy the `entityManager()`-Getter as in:

```
new DomainClass().entityManager;
```