# How to create a custom finder using spring roo

Tags: spring-roo

I have an entity Upgrade which has a set of Product objects.  I want a finder object like findProductsByUpgrade_Name(String name), but I think I need to create this myself as I can't find out how to do this.  Can anyone give me any pointers or point me in the right direction?

Upgrade:

```
package com.company.pr.domain;

import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.entity.RooEntity;
import com.company.pr.domain.UpgradeType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.util.Set;
import com.company.pr.domain.Product;
import java.util.HashSet;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Upgrade {

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private UpgradeType upgrade_type;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();

    private String description;
}
```

Product:

```
package com.company.pr.domain;

import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.entity.RooEntity;
import com.company.pr.domain.PackageType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Product {

    private String product_id;

    private String product_name;

    private String ca_product;

    @ManyToOne
    private PackageType packageType;

    private String description;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if ROO could generate such a finder for you - if you have not tried the *finder list* command thats the way to go.

If you need to create your own HQL/JPQL etc then you should follow the recommended pattern for that, see [Roo - add custom finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075368/roo-add-custom-finder)

Hope that helps you a little step ahead.

Answer (score 2):

You need the other direction of your realtion:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "products")
private Set<Upgrade> upgradets = new HashSet<Upgrade>();
```

then you can make the finder finder add findProduckByUpgrades

HF