# How to generate jspx and controllers files for complex (custom) finders in Spring ROO?

Tags: java, spring-roo

I want to create a complex custom finder and generate jspx file for it.

I have a class called Payment that was generated by spring ROO (please note that actual code was modified in order to simplify things):

```
package com.mystuff.orm;
...
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
public class Payment {

   private Double someValue;
    ...

    // My Custom finder!!
   public static TypedQuery<PaymentSummary> findPaymentStatistics(Calendar fromDate, Calendar toDate) {
    if (fromDate == null || toDate == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Date period argument is required");
    EntityManager em = Payment.entityManager();
    TypedQuery<PaymentSummary> q = em.createQuery("select new com.mystuff.data.PaymentSummary(sum(o.someValue)) from Payment o where o.startDate >= :startDate and o.endDate <= :endDate", PaymentSummary.class);
    q.setParameter("startDate", fromDate);
    q.setParameter("endDate", toDate);
    return q;
   }

}
```

How can I generate jspx files for this query? Whenever I try to run "finder add --finderName findPaymentStatistics" I get an error message:

Dynamic finder is unable to match 'findPaymentStatistics' token of 'findPaymentStatistics' finder definition in Payment.java

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is 'findPaymentStatistics' above is a method you implemented by hand?  If so, then Roo [won't be able to generate the front end for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075368/roo-add-custom-finder).  However, Roo will generate a front end if you have it create the finder code itself.  Roo should be able to generate a similar finder to the one you've coded by hand.  Try running this:

```
roo> finder list --class com.mystuff.orm.Payment --filter start,end
```

That should give you a list of the dynamic finders that Roo can create that include the 'startDate' and 'endDate' parameters of the Payment object.